# Sypder: missing dependeny (parso version)

Tags: spyder

When I fire up Spyder, I recently get the following pop up:
[error message parso dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7vcE.png)

However, the versions seems to correspond.

```
(base) C:\Users\ma.kofler>conda list parso
# packages in environment at C:\Users\ma.xxxxx\Miniconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel parso                     0.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
```

Could anyone help me out?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To fix this problem you need to open the Anaconda Prompt and run there

`conda install parso=0.7.0`

Comment: Hi Carlos, done as you mention but  still remain at parso 0.8.1

Comment: This is the output   environment location: C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\spyderfour

  added / updated specs:
    - parso=0.7.0


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    mkl_random-1.0.4           |   py36h343c172_0         289 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         289 KB

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  mkl_random         pkgs/main::mkl..etc